# Preserve state in jquery menu

Tags: jquery, menu

I have jquery menu that on click shows specific div element. 
I wonder if i refresh page when for example div3 is active(visible), how can i make div3 active again after reload of the page?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a cookie to track state?

Comment: I downloaded jQuery cookie plugin, and it is working now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use #hash tag's in the URL and hash polling to achieve this.

Here is an example:

```
<a href="#showdiv">Click here to show div!</a>

var start_hash = window.location.hash;
var recent_hash = ""; 

process_hash(start_hash);  // Start the initial hash check
setInterval(poll_hash, 100);    // Initialize our hash polling interval

function poll_hash() {
 if (window.location.hash==recent_hash) { return; } // No change in URL hash
 recent_hash = window.location.hash;            // Set to check next time. 
 process_hash(recent_hash);             // Changed hash, lets process
}

// process_hash    
function process_hash(current_hash) {
 // Check for defaults, then set to #home.
 if(!current_hash || current_hash == '') { current_hash="#home"; }

 // Strip the # for the hash
 var hash_id = link_div.match(/[^#]+/g);                

 // conditions for multiple hash tags can go here. 
 if(hash_id == "#showdiv") {
  $("#somediv").show();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is accessed of course via url.com/page.php#showdiv to restore state. If you have multiple elements, or depending on whether you dont want the state to save between clients you may want to use cookies to track the state.